# Can't `ssh` and the `docker exec` in a single command

Tags: ssh, docker, terminal

I want to `ssh` into a remote server that runs a docker engine and then `docker exec` a `bash` in `my-nice-container`, in interactive mode. I want to do all in one shot.

I'm doing this from my local computer:

```
ssh my-site-with-a-docker-engine.example.com docker exec -it my-nice-container bash
```

I get this error: "the input device is not a TTY"

**Question:** How can I force the `ssh` to notify the other side that we are really an interactive terminal?

> Note 1:
>
> If I do this command "splitted", it works:
>
> 1. I first `ssh`,
> 2. I then from inside the `ssh` I type-in the `docker exec`.

> Note 2:
>
> Non-interactive commands work well. For example this works:
>
> ```
> ssh ubuntu@docker-engine-6faeab.hellotripworld.com docker ps -a
> ```

Answer (score 4):

Found. It was `-t`. A first look at the man page https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh and searching for the words "terminal" and "interactive" did not resolve, this is why I asked.

Then I found that "`-t` Force pseudo-tty allocation."

This is checked to work:

```
ssh -t my-site-with-a-docker-engine.example.com docker exec -it my-nice-container bash
```